# ProcessBuilder and cmd

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

Why does

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C","dir");
```

work but

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","dir");
```

does not.
I mean in the latter case the cmd starts but the listing of the directory does not happen.Why is this?

Comment: What does not work? Is an error thrown? Which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the normal behaviour of `cmd.exe` - the same happens on the command line:

```
C:\>cmd dir
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

```
C:\>cmd /c dir
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is ABCD-EF10
...
```

With the first call, you are creating a new (interactive) command interpreter process, `cmd.exe`.
With the second call, you are creating a new command interpreter process and tell it to execute the given command and then exit:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `cmd.exe` works like that. Try this in a command window:

```
cmd dir
```

and

```
cmd /C dir
```

Also have a look at `help cmd` for an explanation.